# Chrome Rich Notifications - длинные уведомления в расширении

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Как в расширении для Google Chrome реализовать(бесконечно) длинные или, хотя бы, разворачивающиеся уведомления? Пробовал сделать это с помощью типа "list", но это не работает. Максимальная длина сейчас - 5 строк.

```
chrome.notifications.create(notificationID, {
        type: 'list',
        title: 'title',
        message: '',
        items: arrayofobjects,
        iconUrl: 'image.png'
    }, function() {
        console.log('noty created');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

вы можете потестировать максимальную длину при использовании Notification API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification , оно не использует движок хрома.

Полностью кастомные уведомления можно сделать, инжектировав во все страницы свой userscript. Нюансы этого смотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725770/chrome-extension-content-scripts-custom-ui).

Comment: При использовании Notification API получается тоже слишком маленькая длина сообщения. Видимо, и впрямь придется делать кастомные.